# Несовпадение размера текстур после сжатия ETC-ETC2 Crunched Unity android

Tags: android, unity3d

Есть изображение в игре, атлас, 2048 на 2048, RGBA.

При сжатии в RGBA Crunched ETC2 его размер составляет всего 0.6 мб

Но в процессе профайлинга ОЗУ, видно, что там он занимает гораздо больше!
В редакторе он занимает 16 мегабайт, что можно объяснить тем, что ETC2 - это формат сжатия для андроида, и на ПК он распаковывается в обычный RGBA 32 bit.

Но проблема в том что и на Android устройстве его размер в памяти составляет 4 мб! Да, это в 4 раза меньше чем в ОЗУ на ПК, но это все равно гораздо больше чем заявленные 0.6 мб

В чем может быть дело, и как жать текстуры для андроида, чтобы их размер соответствовал заявленному в редакторе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы немного не верно трактуете понятие сжатия.

В официальном блоге Unity есть [статья](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2017/11/15/updated-crunch-texture-compression-library/), поясняющая Crunched сжатие. Основная фишка этих типов сжатия как раз заключается в том, что текстура занимает меньше места на дисковом пространстве. Но для того, чтобы использоваться при рендере она распаковывается. Распаковка происходит как раз в момент загрузки в оперативную память. Как описано в статье, при распаковке Crunched сжатия получаем DTX текстуру в памяти, которая будет весить больше, чем исходная сжатая текстура. Такой формат сжатия очень удобен, если нужно уменьшить размер пакета приложения, или загружаемого контента, например бандлов).

Если вы хотите сильно сэкономить на размере текстур в оперативной памяти, можно прибегнуть к паре достаточно сложных трюков, которые будут работать на текстурах с большим содержанием альфы.

1. Разделение альфа канала картинки в отдельную текстуру. В таком случае, под альфу можно выделить текстуру меньшего размера (артефачить сильно не будет) и кроме того, так как в этой текстуре надо хранить информацию только об 1 канале, а тип текстуры можно использовать RGB - можно запихивать альфы разных картинок по всем трем каналам в одном изображении, тем самым умещая 3 альфа атласа в один. Рисовать все это можно будет только через кастомный шейдер, и в целом, идея довольно сложна для реализации.
2. Мало кто обращает внимание, что Unity рисует спрайты на экране  с помощью WireFrames. То есть, для отрисовки изображения используется не квадрат, состоящий из 2 треугольников-полигонов, а сетку, обрезанную по альфе. На этом можно сыграть при упаковке текстур в атласы. То есть собирать текстуры в атлас, по их сетке, игнорируя альфа канал. Что-то подобное реализовали в Playrix и обозвали [Полигональными Атласами](https://habr.com/ru/company/playrix/blog/306554/). А в Unity такое можно сделать либо руками, либо использовать один из плагинов, например [этот](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/sprite-management/spritesharp-mesh-optimizer-37599). Больше о подобной идее можно почитать [здесь на русском](https://agulev.com/utiliti-dlia-razrabotki-igr/) и [здесь на английском](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/using-spritesheets-with-unity). От себя могу добавить, что наиболее хорошо такой подход работает для изометрического арта.